# Creating a barplot - loading a csv issue

Tags: r, csv, error-handling, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a cluster chart/barplot. I have the data in a csv file in Excel which I've imported. So I've tried the `read.csv()` function but it isn't working. Can anyone assist me please? This is the code I've tried:

```
read.csv(filename, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "",)
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :
> 'file' must be a character string or connection

Any help would be great. Thanks.

I have tried creating the barplot without the read.csv but it doesn't do it correctly.  I have also been given code where the quote bit is just ''" which I've tried but that doesn't seem to work either.  And I've tried putting in False instead of True for the header, but I don't see that that would make a difference.  And lastly I've tried adding .csv to the end of my file name.  That resulted in a + sign, but not in me being able to get a graph.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the `filename` argument for the `read.csv` function must be either a string indicating the file's location (e.g. "E:/My files/my_data.csv") or a `connection` object (which is a much more complicated manner of accessing a file, so I won't get into it).  Something like:

```
read.csv("E:/My files/my_data.csv")
```

All the other arguments you specified (`sep`, `dec`, `header`, `fill` and `comment.char`) are equal to their default values, so there is no need to explicitly include them.